# Ubuntu use compiled package instead of apt-get

Tags: apt

I have a compiled binary specifically sun Oracle java that I am using instead of Ubuntu`s apt-get version of java ( what ever it may be ).

I am installing an apt-get package ( maven ) and would like apt-get to use the version of java I have manually installed

I can not install any more packages or tools on the system.
I have what ever Ubuntu LTS 12.04 comes with.

Comment: Are you asking how to specify which `java` for `maven` to use?  Have you set `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Apt-get doesn't use Java. Did you mean you want Maven to use a different installation of Java? Do you want to use it only for Maven or for everything?

Comment: I am using apt-get to intsall maven. I would like apt-get to not install java as part of maven`s dependencies or alternatively add my binary to apt-get

Comment: You have said what you want to do, but you haven't said why. If any sun java package will do, you can build (if not already available) a sun java binary (deb) package for Ubuntu. If maven depends on a different version of java, you could also build a custom maven deb which depends on sun java. This of course assumes maven will work with sun java. I have no idea if that is the case.

Comment: In order to "add your binary to apt-get" you're going to have to build it as a deb package that Provides the java keywords that the maven package Requires. This is *possible* but most people who know enough about software packaging to know how to do it also know better than to do it unless they *really* need to. Take that as advice and elaborate on *why* it's so important to you to use the 'specifically sun Oracle java compiled binary' instead.

Comment: What else graphics card bindings that are available through OpenGL

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but is not possible. Maven has dependencies of Java and these can't be ignored:

```
apt-cache depends maven
maven
 |Depends: default-jre
 |Depends: default-jre-headless
```

So, whenever you try to install maven, java will get installed. The only way to get around this is packaging your own version of Java and install it in your system, otherwise I don't see any other safe way you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `apt-get install maven` with the `--nodeps` flag, but make sure you have all other dependencies of `maven` installed.

Comment: Note that apt will attempt to fix these dependencies every single time you try to update or upgrade, because *solving dependency issues is literally its job*.